# Add Support for Meta Stack Overflow to the Stack Overflow iOS App

Tags: feature-request, meta, android-app, ios-app

From the [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/16/stack-overflow-official-app-launches-ios-android/):

> If you decide to download both apps, your notifications will be split between the two. Your Stack Overflow notifications will appear in the Stack Overflow app, and all other Stack Exchange notifications will appear in the Stack Exchange app.

It doesn't make sense that Meta Stack Overflow would be treated as a separate community outside of the Stack Overflow app.  Push notifications for main would go to one app and meta for another?  That doesn't make sense to me.

Please add Meta support to the Stack Overflow app.